# django-twitter-api error: No module named utils

Tags: python, django, importerror

I am working on an application that would take a  tweet from user and then as a result, it will tell the sentiment of that tweet. For this, i installed django-twitter-api. It installed correctly but when i do:

```
 from twitter_api.utils import api
```

it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "(stdin)", line 1, in (module)
Import Error: No module named utils.
```

I followed all the instructions from https://github.com/ramusus/django-twitter-api and made the required changes to my .settings.py file in my django project folder. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming as there is no `utils.py` file inside the `twitter_api` folder so how can it import that. Try using `from twitter_api import api`, it should work, according to the structure of the repository given.

Comment: It now says, "No module named importlib"

Comment: Are you using the same python and django version as used in django-twitter-api?